# Minimize $z=e^{-x_{1}}+e^{-2 x_{2}}$ Subject to $\quad x_{1}+x_{2} \leq 1 \ , x_{1}, x_{2} \geq 0$ without KKT

Tags: inequality, optimization, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, constraints

I want to minimize $z=e^{-x_{1}}+e^{-2 x_{2}}$
subject to $\quad x_{1}+x_{2} \leq 1 \ ,  x_{1}, x_{2} \geq 0$ without using the KKT conditions. The restrain is on regular inequalities like Cauchy or Jensen ( some of the common known and used)
I don't know how to proceed. I tried to lower bound and get that bound to equality.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [A.M-G.M inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), we have $$e^{-x_1}+e^{-2x_2}=\dfrac{e^{-x_1}}{2}+\dfrac{e^{-x_1}}{2}+e^{-2x_2} \geq 3 \left(\dfrac{e^{-2x_1-2x_2}}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \geq 3\left(\dfrac{e^{-2}}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \;.$$

Comment: To make the answer complete, worth adding that this is achieved for $x_2 = \frac{1+\log 2}{3}$ and $x_1=1-x_2$.